# ASP .netCore WebApi connection to RabbitMQ

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, asp.net-core-webapi, iis-10

I had RabbitMQ exception:

> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the
>   specified endpoints were reachable --->
>   RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException: Connection failed
>   ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.

Conditions of reproducing are very unusual. I have ASP .netCore 1.0 Web Api application which creates 4 message publishers therefore (with same host name, virtual host, user name, password).

There are several apps are connected to the RabbitMQ with the same settings (host name, virtual host, user name, password) as a WebApi service. As a result I have 18 connections to the RabbitMQ.

It works fine, but when WebApi service is recycled I get exception. It means that in the same time recycled service try to dispose connections (and successfully dispose when it becomes unloaded) and the new Service instance trying to connect ti RabbitMQ and get exception.

But if I stop service, wait for unloading and start Service once again there are no problems.

I tried to find documentation about connection limit per user, TCP connections limit but as I understood there are no reasons for RabbitMQ to refuse connection

Maybe anybody know anything about such error?

Comment: is there anything in the RabbitMQ logs?

Comment: Error message `broker unreachable` and reproduction conditions suggest that the problem is not on RabbitMQ side. Broker does not receive the connection requests. There is something happening on the client side (rabbitmq client or the app itself). If RabbitMQ is refusing connections, you will get different error message and something will be in the RabbitMQ log.